# Can we Disable or Prevent "Commit-and-Push" in Eclipse EGit?

Tags: eclipse, egit

We migrated to Git a few months ago. To ease the transition, we adopted using the EGit plugin for Eclipse. The Git Staging view includes 2 buttons: "Commit" and "Commit and Push"
[image: Git Staging view in Eclipse]

We trained the team in a Commit-Pull-Push workflow. But the "Commit and Push" button has become popular in practice. It causes some minor workflow issues and I am discouraging its use, but would love to disable or remove the option until we have a deeper team-wide understanding of Git.

Is this possible? Is there a setting, property or option to disable "Commit and Push"?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO we can't make "Commit and Push" button disabled.

EGIT doesn't provide any preference option to disable this. If you want to remove/disable this button your have to edit the source code of EGIT eclipse plug in then build it for yourself.

Instead you try NOT to use GIT staging view for committing purpose but use commit dialog for committing.
Disable the preference `Use Staging View to commit instead of Commit Dialog` in `Windows > Preferences > Git > Committing`

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but I don't see benefit in that change. The Commit dialog still has the Commit-and-Push action, and has less overall information. E.G. in the Git Staging view it is clearer what is the current repository and branch, and the Staged/Unstaged status of the files.

Comment: Yes. But no hope. You have to modify the source code of EGIT plugin and build is yourself and have it in your eclipse installation.